# how to append input box to same page

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have a select menu, and what happens is, if the users select `Other`, another menu input field is supposed to pop up below that allows them to clarify. I tried this below, however, `document.write` writes another page. How do I append it to the current page!

```js
        function otherFunc() {
            var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
            var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
            console.log(selectedValue)
            if (selectedValue == "Other") {
                document.write(' <div class="group"><div class="col-25"><label>Please clarify if "Other"</label></div><div class="col-75"><input type="text" name="other" required></div><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span></div>')
            }
        }
```

```html
<select name="relations" id="selectBox" style="text-transform: none;" class="select" required onchange="otherFunc()">
                    <option value="">Choose</option>
                    <option value="Son">Son</option>
                    <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                    <option value="Other Relative">Other Relative</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: You can also include that input in your markup right from the start and use CSS to show or hide it. You can add or remove style classes to elements with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a blank div below select. and then use innerhtml as shown

```js
    function otherFunc() {
            var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
            var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
            console.log(selectedValue)
            if (selectedValue == "Other") {
                document.getElementById("other").innerHTML = ' <div class="group"><div class="col-25"><label>Please clarify if "Other"</label></div><div class="col-75"><input type="text" name="other" required></div><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span></div>'
            }
        }
```

```html
 <select name="relations" id="selectBox" style="text-transform: none;" class="select" required onchange="otherFunc()">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="Son">Son</option>
        <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
        <option value="Other Relative">Other Relative</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <div id="other"></div>
```

Comment: this worked the best! it didn't require any extra work. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I added a semicolon after your console.log statement and it seems to be working.

```js
function otherFunc() {
                var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
                var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
                if (selectedValue == "Other") {
                    document.body.innerHTML += ' <div class="group"><div class="col-25"><label>Please clarify if "Other"</label></div><div class="col-75"><input type="text" name="other" required></div><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span></div>';
                }
            }
```

```html
<select name="relations" id="selectBox" style="text-transform: none;" class="select" required onchange="otherFunc()">
                        <option value="">Choose</option>
                        <option value="Son">Son</option>
                        <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                        <option value="Other Relative">Other Relative</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: @Spectric My bad, missed that bit. Amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.setAttribute('class', 'group');
div.append('<div class="col-25"><label>Please clarify if "Other"</label></div><div class="col-75"><input type="text" name="other" required></div><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>');
document.getElementsByTagName('body').append(div);
```